# Used brew to install latest chromedriver, keep getting the same error, his version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run some code using **Rselenium** and keep running in to the same problem.

Whenever I run the code i get the error:

```bash
Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 106
Current browser version is 111.0.5563.64 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:caa:f7db:27fc:1860%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.2.1', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I tried installing the updated chromedriver using brew yet it doesn't seem to run the correct version for the code. Anyone got any suggestions?

I **tried installing** the updated chromedriver **using brew** yet it doesn't seem to run the correct version for the code. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Install chromium==106 or chromedriver==111